# How to estimate the parameters of a Burr XII distribution using MLE

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood

I have a dataset and I am wondering if would be a reasonable fit for a number of distribution types.

I was looking to fit the Burr XII distribution in Python initially (using scipy library) and then validate the result using the R actuar library.

As I received different results for the estimates of the shape1, shape2 and scale parameters between the two libraries I would like to understand how to compute the estimates myself (i.e. outside of actuar/scipy)

Just to give an idea of the differences:

In R (actuar)

```
#shape1 R  =   0.066311696290154
#shape2 R   = 13.412776829494927
#scale R  =    4.3465794231141
```

In Python (Python)

```
#shape1 Py = 108.33525966683732
#shape2 Py =   0.008276941245923156
#scale Py =    4.388707206455431
```

From what I can gather it appears that the shape1 & 2 are flipped between Python and R.

Here is some sample code to reproduce in R:

```
library(actuar)

burr_sample <- c(5.35382659682693, 4.74764035328555, 6.41688382297086, 4.70194010676229,
4.45113004935033, 4.50611840443683, 8.03060660585978, 4.5695082533874,
4.48052843925116, 5.05598541072842, 4.99368090343132, 4.63153147946491,
4.68443593804105, 5.02826922164524, 210.415754831859, 114.311867979766,
611.092749788117, 4.502751256927, 4.57870681149377, 5.11299025815068,
5.31665861351517, 14.8465590392403, 5.58683130567932,15.9141068218137,
11.6050958855081, 10.175418658569, 109.160688760136, 8.28179845669206,
4.54159063565775, 22.8318960824204, 8.82622790142304, 4.88362864083956,
9.42213684934793, 84.7237613685393, 7.60704879618404, 46.393548985959,
4.86797703394291, 89.5695808475361, 8.43029961651323, 4.67889028482232,
75.3616899071995, 5.31730051442045, 18.729798449272, 9.9174137219138,
79.9573773033068, 15.069030596827, 66.7713319465588, 11.8175710845523,
7.87392052996755, 3072.60557504056, 14.3601404431787, 5.03732319328952)

burr_fit <- fitdist(burr_sample,"burr",method="mle", start = list(shape1 = 0.24, 
                                                                  shape2 = 0.5, 
                                                                  rate = 5))

summary(burr_fit) # shape1 =  0.066311696290154  shape2 = 13.412776829494927, scale = 1/0.240613220041504 = 4.3465794231141
```

```
In Python:

burr_sample= [5.35382659682693, 4.74764035328555, 6.41688382297086, 4.70194010676229,
4.45113004935033, 4.50611840443683, 8.03060660585978, 4.5695082533874,
4.48052843925116, 5.05598541072842, 4.99368090343132, 4.63153147946491,
4.68443593804105, 5.02826922164524, 210.415754831859, 114.311867979766,
611.092749788117, 4.502751256927, 4.57870681149377, 5.11299025815068,
5.31665861351517, 14.8465590392403, 5.58683130567932,15.9141068218137,
11.6050958855081, 10.175418658569, 109.160688760136, 8.28179845669206,
4.54159063565775, 22.8318960824204, 8.82622790142304, 4.88362864083956,
9.42213684934793, 84.7237613685393, 7.60704879618404, 46.393548985959,
4.86797703394291, 89.5695808475361, 8.43029961651323, 4.67889028482232,
75.3616899071995, 5.31730051442045, 18.729798449272, 9.9174137219138,
79.9573773033068, 15.069030596827, 66.7713319465588, 11.8175710845523,
7.87392052996755, 3072.60557504056, 14.3601404431787, 5.03732319328952]

random.seed(421)
burr_fit = stats.burr12.fit(burr_sample, 0.5 , 0.24 , floc=0, scale = 5)
print(burr_fit)
(108.34090735484176, 0.008357900741996344, 0, 4.388113415121694)
```

If folks have any suggestions of sources to obtain equations to estimate parameters via MLE that would be much appreciated.

I am reading the following paper: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Fu-Kwun-Wang/publication/227617903_Robust_regression_for_estimating_the_Burr_XII_parameters_with_outliers/links/5407c9aa0cf2bba34c247139/Robust-regression-for-estimating-the-Burr-XII-parameters-with-outliers.pdf

The paper looks to estimate parameters c and k, please let me know if this is a useful place to start.

Finally, I should add that if I generate a burr xii distribution using:

```
rburr(50, 2,2, 0.2)
```

I get very similar results parameter results in  R and Python. So I am wondering if my sample dataset is causing issues with parameter estimates.

Regards
Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

Its better to write your own likelihood and check. Due to couple of observations, 611.092749788117 and  3072.60557504056 the optimizer would really struggle.

I would reparametrize with exp() of your parameters in likelihood and leverage unconstrained optimizer. I'm able to match your Python output.

To answer your question: the discrepancies between `R`s `fitdistrplus::fitdist` and `Python` is due to data with extreme observations and parameterization/optimizer.

```
## Burr Density (shape = {c,k}, location = mu, scale = sigma)

dBURR <- function(x,c,k,mu=0,sigma=1){
  
  return((k*c/sigma)*((x-mu)/sigma)^(c-1)*(1+((x-mu)/sigma)^c)^-(k+1))
  
}

 ## Define Likelihood
   
blik <- function(theta,x){
  
  c <- exp(theta[1])
  
  k <- exp(theta[2])
  
  mu <- 0
  
  sigma <- exp(theta[3])

  bll <- c(((dBURR(x,c,k,mu,sigma))))
  
  return(-sum(log(bll)))  
  
}

brmod <- optim(c(1,1,1), fn = blik,x=burr_sample)
exp(brmod$par)


[1] 108.342578879   0.008355619   4.388801101
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an extended comment on the good observation of @forecaster that the two extreme values in the data are causing numerical issues that double precision arithmetic can't handle.  And in fact it appears that there is no maximum likelihood estimate for $c$ (or at best $c$ is extremely large).

The log of the likelihood is given by

$$\log(L)=-(k+1) \sum _{i=1}^n \log \left(\left(\frac{x_i}{\sigma }\right)^c+1\right)+(c-1) \sum _{i=1}^n \log (x_i)-c n \log (\sigma )+n \log (c)+n \log (k)$$

One can find the maximum likelihood estimate of $k$ in terms of $c$ and $\sigma$:

$$\hat{k}=\frac{n}{\sum _{i=1}^n \log \left(\left(\frac{x_i}{\hat{\sigma}}\right)^\hat{c}+1\right)}$$

So that makes it a maximization problem of just 2 parameters: $c$ and $\sigma$.

$$n \left(-\log \left(\sum _{i=1}^n \log \left(\left(\frac{x_i}{\sigma }\right)^c+1\right)\right)-c \log (\sigma )+\log (c)+\log (n)-1\right)-\sum _{i=1}^n \log \left(\left(\frac{x_i}{\sigma }\right)^c+1\right)+(c-1) \sum _{i=1}^n \log (x_i)$$

Using *Mathematica* where we can rationalize the input data (meaning converting the data to rationale numbers) we can avoid numerical round-off errors:

```
x = {5.35382659682693, 4.74764035328555, 6.41688382297086, 4.70194010676229,
  4.45113004935033, 4.50611840443683,  8.03060660585978, 4.5695082533874,
  4.48052843925116, 5.05598541072842, 4.99368090343132, 4.63153147946491,
  4.68443593804105, 5.02826922164524, 210.415754831859, 114.311867979766,
  611.092749788117, 4.502751256927, 4.57870681149377, 5.11299025815068,
  5.31665861351517, 14.8465590392403, 5.58683130567932, 15.9141068218137, 
  11.6050958855081, 10.175418658569, 109.160688760136, 8.28179845669206,
  4.54159063565775, 22.8318960824204, 8.82622790142304, 4.88362864083956,
  9.42213684934793, 84.7237613685393, 7.60704879618404, 46.393548985959, 
  4.86797703394291, 89.5695808475361, 8.43029961651323, 4.67889028482232,
  75.3616899071995, 5.31730051442045, 18.729798449272, 9.9174137219138,
  79.9573773033068, 15.069030596827, 66.7713319465588, 11.8175710845523, 
  7.87392052996755, 3072.60557504056, 14.3601404431787, 5.03732319328952};
(* Rationalize input data *)
x = Rationalize[x, 0];

(* Construct log of likelihood *)
n = Length[y]
logL = n Log[c] - n c Log[\[Sigma]] + 
  n Log[k] + (c - 1) Sum[Log[x[i]], {i, 1, n}] - 
  (1 + k) Sum[Log[1 + (x[i]/\[Sigma])^c], {i, 1, n}]
mlek = Solve[D[logL, k] == 0, k][[1]] (* mle for k in terms of c and sigma *)
logLcsigma = logL //. mlek /. Log[u_/v_] -> Log[u] - Log[v] // Expand // Simplify
```

A contour plot of the log of the likelihood for $c$ and $\sigma$ looks like the following:

```
ContourPlot[logLcsigma, {c, 20, 450}, {\[Sigma], 4.4, 4.5},
 Contours -> {-191.2, -191.3, -191.4, -191.5, -192, -193, -194, -105},
 ContourShading -> None, ContourLabels -> (Text[#3, {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &)]
```

[image: Contour plot of the log of the likelihood]

This plot suggests that the value of $c$ that would maximize the log of the likelihood is much larger than 450.  If we choose a value for $\sigma$ at 4.43 and plot the log of the likelihood (after subtracting off a constant to get a readable plot) for $\sigma$, we see the following:

```
base = logLcsigma /. {c -> 800, \[Sigma] -> Rationalize[4.43, 0]};
t = Table[{c, (logLcsigma /. \[Sigma] -> Rationalize[4.43, 0]) - base}, {c, 800, 1200}];
ListPlot[t, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"c", "Log of likelihood\n-constant"}]
```

[image: Log of likelihood for large values of c]

We see that the outrageously large values of $c$ are resulting in larger and larger values of the log of the likelihood.

My conclusion is that the maximum likelihood solution doesn't exist for fitting a Burr Type XII distribution (also known as the Singh-Maddala distribution) with this data.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for pointing out  singh maddala Distribution. More general form of Burr distribution is Weibull Gamma compound distribution. https://www.jstor.org/stable/1402945

Comment: @forecaster Thanks.  And even removing the two extreme points doesn't appear to result in a good fit (not that extreme points should be automatically tossed).